# Coordinates scale not correct when drawing a polyline on an View

Tags: android, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I want to draw a `polyline` on a `view`. I don't want to draw it on a `MapView` because I only want the `polyline` without any background.

I have the `polyline` coordinates and I also have its bounds (northeast and southwest coordinates).

The idea was to create a custom `view` and draw the path there. The problem I believe I'm having is with the scale. I can convert the `LatLng` coordinates to `x` and `y` coordinates but the polyline that is shown on the `view` is too small. The `view` is set with a `64dp` width and height.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
public PolylineView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    polylineSize = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.polyline_size);
    setupAttributes(attrs);
}

private void setupAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
    // Obtain a typed array of attributes
    TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PolylineView, 0, 0);
    // Extract custom attributes into member variables
    try {
        polylineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PolylineView_polylineColor, Color.BLACK);

    } finally {
        // TypedArray objects are shared and must be recycled.
        a.recycle();
    }

    polyline = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    polyline.setAntiAlias(true);
    polyline.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    polyline.setStrokeWidth(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    polyline.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    polyline.setColor(polylineColor);

    path = new Path();
    smp = new SphericalMercatorProjection(polylineSize);
}

@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    point = smp.toPoint(polylineCoordinates.get(0));

    path.moveTo((float) (point.x * scale), (float) (point.y * scale));

    for (int i = 1; i < polylineCoordinates.size(); i++) {
        point = smp.toPoint(polylineCoordinates.get(i));

        path.lineTo((float) (point.x * scale), (float) (point.y * scale));
    }

    canvas.drawPath(path, polyline);
}

public void setPolyline(List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates, RealmLatLngBounds polylineBounds) {
    this.polylineBounds = polylineBounds;
    this.polylineCoordinates = polylineCoordinates;

    //Find the scale
    Point northeast = smp.toPoint(polylineBounds.getNortheast());
    Point southwest = smp.toPoint(polylineBounds.getSouthwest());
    scale = polylineSize / Math.max(Math.max(northeast.x, southwest.x), Math.max(northeast.y, southwest.y));

    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}
```

After can I transform the `polyline` coordinates so that the full size of the `view` is used?

Edit:

One of the problems that I can see is when converting to `x` and `y`, values are two close (precision)
[image]

Comment: @pskink I did  this `scale = Math.max(northeast.x / southwest.x, southwest.y / northeast.y);` but still with no success

Comment: no. Still the same problem. See the picture I've attached. Probably something to do with precision.

Comment: @pskink Thanks. It was very useful. I'm still having problems because items are inside a recyclerview but will find the answer.

Comment: it does not matter if it is inside recyclerview or not

Comment: I manage to solve it. Many thanks. Don't you want to put your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: if you solved that, write self answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @pskink I've managed to achieve this

```
private int polylineSize;
private Paint polyline;
private SphericalMercatorProjection smp;


PointF northeast;
PointF[] points;
PointF southwest;

Path originalPath;
Path transformedPath;


public PolylineView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public PolylineView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    polylineSize = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.polyline_size);
    setupAttributes(attrs);
}

public PolylineView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    polylineSize = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.polyline_size);
    setupAttributes(attrs);
}

private void setupAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
    // Obtain a typed array of attributes
    TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PolylineView, 0, 0);
    // Extract custom attributes into member variables
    int polylineColor;
    try {
        polylineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PolylineView_polylineColor, Color.BLACK);

    } finally {
        // TypedArray objects are shared and must be recycled.
        a.recycle();
    }

    polyline = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    polyline.setAntiAlias(true);
    polyline.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    polyline.setStrokeWidth(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    polyline.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    polyline.setColor(polylineColor);

    smp = new SphericalMercatorProjection(polylineSize);

}

public void setPolylineData(List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates, RealmLatLngBounds polylineBounds) {

    originalPath = new Path();
    transformedPath = new Path();

    Point point = smp.toPoint(polylineBounds.getNortheast());
    northeast = new PointF((float) point.x, (float) point.y);

    point = smp.toPoint(polylineBounds.getSouthwest());
    southwest = new PointF((float) point.x, (float) point.y);

    points = new PointF[polylineCoordinates.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.size(); i++) {
        point = smp.toPoint(polylineCoordinates.get(i));
        points[i] = new PointF((float) point.x, (float) point.y);
    }

    originalPath.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

    for (PointF p : points) {
        originalPath.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
    }

    RectF src = new RectF(southwest.x, northeast.y, northeast.x, southwest.y);
    RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, polylineSize, polylineSize);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    originalPath.transform(matrix, transformedPath);

    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(transformedPath, polyline);
}
```

This view is used on a `RecyclerView` and the data is set on `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: if you want to use temporary array of `PointF[] points;` then do not use `originalPath.transform()`, instead use `float[] points;` array of points (with size `polylineCoordinates.size() * 2`) and simply call `matrix.mapPoints(points)`, then use that transformed points to build your `Path` - that way there is  no need for two `Path`s