# Android save polygon as image and set 1:10000 scale

Tags: android, dictionary, scale, polygon

I am creating an Android application where I need to draw polygon on Google map and then save polygon as any format picture. [Example of polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1T5c.png) This is how I am creating the polygon:

```
polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions
                    .strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 100, 0)));
```

Another thing I need is to set the scale to 1:10000. Is there a zoom level that is equivalent to 1:10000?
When saving polygon fill color isn't needed. All I need is outlining but it has to be scaled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use polyline instead of polygon. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204301/android-get-polyline-as-image) article can help you saving polyline to image. Im not sure about scaling though.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me with image part but Im still dont know how to get scale right.